# Do named event handlers consume more memory than anonymous ones in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Does this code

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("event", function (event) {
    /* some code */
  });
}
```

consume more memory than

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div");
function handler(event) {
  /* some code */
}
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("event", handler);
}
```

this?
If I'm not mistaken, the first code stores the event handler for every item in the list, but the second code does it only once. Is that true?

Comment: tldr / face value: **no**. Longer answer: the shown code has two _semantically different_ cases. It is the _number_ of function objects which can affect memory (small per-instance overheads, closure bindings, and implementation sharing details), not if they have a "name" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

First of all, all functions have names. In the case of anonymous functions, the name is simply the empty string. So the difference between the two cases is a savings of about 6 bytes, because the name of one function is `"handler"` while the name of the other is `""`.

Perhaps what you were wondering is if a new function is created on each iteration of the loop in the first version. That shouldn't be necessary in this case.

This depends on whether the function contains any references to `i`. If it does, each iteration will need to create a closure that references that iteration's scope of `i`. There will be just one function, but multiple closures.

However, if the two snippets are intended to be equivalent, `handler()` can't refer to `i`. So in this case there should be no need for multiple closures.